# setting Delegate and datasource of a UITableView set inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview, swift2

The title basically says it all; I want to set the delegate and dataSource of a tableView we'll call `myTable`. the way I'd normally do this is by establishing an outlet connection to the table from the storyboard then set the delegate and dataSource, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTable.delegate = self
    myTable.dataSource = self
}
```

However, because my Table is inside a cell of a `UICollectionView`, I'm getting the error `"The myTable Outlet from the myCollectionViewController to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets Cannot be connected to repeating content"`

I understand the error but my question is; How do I set the delegate and datasource now that my usual method isn't available.

Comment: Have you implemented UITableViewDatasource and UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: @Tander What I'm trying to is is have an app that separates a list of players into a variable amount of teams (evenly, based on their rating). I'm making a collectionView of tableViews so that I can have a variable amount of tables based on the number of teams desired, with each table containing the players names. (The table it's self isn't inside the collectionView, but in the collectionViewCell, if that's what's bothering you)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out. I linked the `myTable` outlet inside the collectionViewCell class (we'll call `myCollectionViewCell`) and set it's delegate and dataSource inside the `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method as follows

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    cell.myTable.dataSource = self
    cell.myTable.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```